# How can I make graph in LaTeX, where nodes are such as in image

Tags: latex, tex, tabular, xypic

I want to create graph with nodes as in the image:

[image]

I wrote an example graph with `\xymatrix` - that's OK. I added circles with `&*+[Fo]`, that's OK too. I added table inside first circle with `\begin{tabular}` - it is OK. But table needs to be rotated by -45 degrees. When i use `isorot` package to rotate it, first - it rotates not against center, but against corner, and, more sadly, `xymatrix` then can't determine circle size, and it shrinks.

How can i rotate table in next example?

```
$$\xymatrix{&*+[Fo]{
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
2&3\\
\hline
4&5
\end{tabular}
}\ar@{-}[r]\ar@{-}[dd]\ar@{-}[rrd]&*+[Fo]{3}\ar@{-}[lld]\ar@{-}[ldd]\ar@{-}[dd]\ar@{-}[rdd]\ar@{-}[rd]& \\ *+[Fo]{1}\ar@{-}[rrr] &&&*+[Fo]{4}\ar@{-}[ld] \\ &*+[Fo]{7}&*+[Fo]{6}\ar@{-}[l]&*+[Fo]{5}& }$$
```

Comment: Maybe try http://tex.stackexchange.com